# Can't use GPU in Magick++ after enabling OpenCL

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, magick++

I wanted to use GPU in Magick++ functions of my project. I've built ImageMagick using [this](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick-Windows) tutorial (OpenCL enabled). The convert.exe file after the built says that OpenCL is enabled. I've included the necessary headers and libs (CORE_RL_Magick++_.lib, CORE_RL_MagickCore_.lib, CORE_RL_MagickWand_.lib). I've also set a IMAGEMAGICK_OPENCL_CACHE_DIR system variable with a path (to store the necessary file). I'm using Windows and Visual Studio.
This is my code:

```
...
#include <Magick++.h>
#include <MagickCore/MagickCore.h>
#include <MagickWand/MagickWand.h>
#include <MagickCore\accelerate-private.h>
...

using namespace Magick;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    EnableOpenCL();
    InitializeMagick(NULL);
    EnableOpenCL(); // Executed this after InitializeMagick too to be sure. Maybe it's needed to be executed after InitializeMagick().

    Image img;
    img.read("F:/tmp/test/22/7.png");

    // These two functions should use GPU. But they don't. :
    img.gaussianBlur(15, 3);
    img.edge();
}
```

The code gives no errors but as you can see my code has functions that ImageMagick can use GPU in them. But it does not. It only uses CPU. Also, ImageMagick generates no files in the path set by IMAGEMAGICK_OPENCL_CACHE_DIR.
What part of it is wrong?

**Edit:**

```
C:\Users\User1>convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.8-4 Q16 x64 2018-06-29 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2018 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Visual C++: 190024210
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules OpenCL OpenMP
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo flif freetype gslib heic jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr lzma openexr pangocairo png ps raw rsvg tiff webp xml zlib
```

Also, my GPU supports OpenCL.

Comment: Does your Imagemagick compile include OpenCL? What version of Imagemagick. Please show what you get from `convert -version` for Imagemagick 6 or `magick -version` for Imagemagick 7. Is your Graphic Processor compatible with OpenCL?

Comment: @fmw42 Just edited it.

Comment: I do not use Magick++, but I would suggest you first try doing the same in the command line and see if that works. I do not have a compatible GPU, so really cannot comment much further, but check http://www.imagemagick.org/script/opencl.php for any hints about your issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer**

If setting `MAGICK_OCL_DEVICE` has no effect, and/or `EnableOpenCl` returns `false`, then OpenCL kernels can not be loaded one the targeted platform/device. The behavior of ImageMagick is to emit a `DelegateWarning` (not error), and fail-back to the CPU.

I suspect that this is the case, and that the reasons *why* are logged to file named `magick_badcl_build.log`, and the actual OpenCL code that failed is written to `magick_badcl.cl`. Both files should be posted to the [developer forums](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/) for review.

Also, the environment variable should be `MAGICK_OPENCL_CACHE_DIR`, not `IMAGEMAGICK_OPENCL_CACHE_DIR`. I think the documentation is wrong.

> From opencl.c
>
> ```c
>  home=GetEnvironmentValue("MAGICK_OPENCL_CACHE_DIR");
>  if (home == (char *) NULL)
>  {
>    home=GetEnvironmentValue("XDG_CACHE_HOME");
>    if (home == (char *) NULL)
>      home=GetEnvironmentValue("LOCALAPPDATA");
>    if (home == (char *) NULL)
>      home=GetEnvironmentValue("APPDATA");
>    if (home == (char *) NULL)
>      home=GetEnvironmentValue("USERPROFILE");
>  }
> ```

---

**Original Answer**

Use the method `InitImageMagickOpenCL` to control the OpenCL device management, not `EnableOpenCl` (which will auto select the best device, and the best device is usually the CPU).

```cpp
cl_uint platformCount;
cl_platform_id platforms[4];
cl_uint deviceCount;
cl_device_id devices[8];
cl_device_id * user_selected_GPU = nullptr;
clGetPlatformIDs(4, platforms, &platformCount);
// Grap the first GPU off the first platform.
// !!! Check docs as this is a _very_ bad example. !!!
if (platformCount > 0) {
    clGetDeviceIDs(platforms[0], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 8, devices, &deviceCount);
    if (deviceCount > 0) {
        user_selected_GPU = devices[0];
    }
}
if (user_selected_GPU) {
    MagickCore::ExceptionInfo * exception = MagickCore::AcquireExceptionInfo();
    MagickCore::InitImageMagickOpenCL(
          MagickCore::MAGICK_OPENCL_DEVICE_SELECT_USER,
          user_selected_GPU,
          nullptr,
          exception
    );
} else {
    // No GPU found... 
}
```

Usually you won't need to bother defining what device to run on as ImageMagick will pull system & environment information. On my mac, for example, the CPU will always be selected out of the pool of devices. If I would prefer to use GPU directly, I can define this at runtime with environment variables.

```
 MAGICK_OCL_DEVICE=GPU ./my_opencl_enabled_magick_application
```

Comment: Using `MAGICK_OCL_DEVICE=GPU` had no effect and I could not use your code because the methods and types were not defined (no InitImageMagickOpenCL or cl_uint was declared in the headers(I've searched all) for example). Even though I've built the ImageMagick with OpenCL enabled.

Comment: The only thing inside `magick_badcl.log` is this: "ptxas error   : Entry function 'WaveletDenoise' uses too much shared data (0x4030 bytes, 0x4000 max)."
`magick_badcl.cl` is not readable. How can I know that it emits a `DelegateWarning`?
Also, could you please tell me how did you use `InitImageMagickOpenCL`? Because I don't have that function!

Comment: The message is telling you that the device / platform doesn't have enough shared memory for ImageMagick Kernels. I'm not an expert here, but double check the hardware specification / data-sheets. Ensure that `OpenCL 2.x` is listed. If you have `OpenCL 1.x` then you may need to downgrade ImageMagick to an earlier version. The developer forums are a good place to find out which version will support your hardware.